# Dual of a locally convex space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. Suppose $E$ is a subset of $ X^*$ (The space of continuous linear functionals). For every $\phi\in E$, define seminorm $p_\phi: X\to [0,\infty)$ such that $p_\infty (x)= |\phi(x)|$. If $\tau$ is the topology generated by these seminorms and $(X,\tau)$ is locally convex space then $(X,\tau)^* = span(E)$.

I do not have any idea about it. Please help me. Thank so much.

Comment: One idea: by the definition of $\tau$, all the elements of $E$ are continuous, so all the linear combinations of elements of $E$ are continuous.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla : I think We should show that every $\phi\in (X,\tau)^*$ is $\|.\|-$continuous and conversely. From your idea, I think you claim every element of $E$ is $\tau -$ continuous.

Comment: In this case there is no norm. And $(X,\tau)^*$ is the dual with respect to $\tau$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla : I edited it.

Comment: Since by assumption, $E$ is a subset of the space of norm-continuous linear functionals, it is clear that every $\lambda \in \operatorname{span} E$ is norm-continuous. By definition of $\tau$, it is elementary that every $\lambda\in \operatorname{span} E$ is $\tau$-continuous. The not-quite-trivial part, and the one you need to spend a little work proving is that _every_ $\tau$-continuous linear functional on $X$ belongs to $\operatorname{span} E$.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709781/intersection-of-kernels-implies-linear-dependence-of-functionals

Comment: @PhoemueX : Thanks for your helpful comment. Now I can prove it.