# linear independence in a dual pair

Tags: linear-algebra, topological-vector-spaces

The following is an excerpt from the *Topological Vector Spaces* by Schaefer:

[image]

I don't see how the underscored sentence work. Suppose
$$
\langle x,y_n\rangle=0
$$
for all $x\in F_n$. Why this implies
$$
y_n\in\hbox{span}\{y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n\}?
$$
I guess it might have something to do with the direct sum $F=F_n+M_n$. But I don't see the connection.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709781/intersection-of-kernels-implies-linear-dependence-of-functionals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $y' = y_n - \langle \overline{x}_1,y_n\rangle y_1 - \langle \overline{x}_2,y_n\rangle y_2 - \cdots - \langle \overline{x}_{n-1},y_n\rangle y_{n-1}$.

1. Can you prove that $y'$ vanishes on all $\overline{x}_i$ and therefore on $M_n$?
2. Can you prove that $y'$ vanishes on all $x \in F_n$?

*Now* use the direct sum and conclude what $y'$ must be, and what that implies.

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{x}_1$ in your answer?

Comment: Yeah, forgot about overlines. EDIT: put them in.

Comment: OK. By the direct sum property, (1) and (2) implies that $\langle x,y'\rangle=0$ for all $x\in X$ and thus $y'=0$ (since $F$ and $G$ are in duality).

Comment: That's correct!