# linear independence in a dual pair and its consequence

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

This is a follow-up question to a previous one:

[linear independence in a dual pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1492429/9464).

The following is from the *Topological Vector Spaces* by Schaefer:

[image]

The corollary has been proven independently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/710241/9464). Could anyone help me understand how it could be derived directly from the theorem in the blue box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing dependent $f_i$, we can WLOG assume that $f_i$ are independent for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Assume that $g$ is not a linear combination of $f_i$, that is $f_i$ and $g$ together are $n+1$ linear independent functionals. By the theorem, there exist $n+1$ vectors $x_i$ with the Kronecker's delta property. One of those vectors, $x_{n+1}$, is such that $f_i(x_{n+1})=\delta_{i,n+1}=0$, but $g(x_{n+1})=\delta_{n+1,n+1}=1$. It contradicts the assumption about the kernel inclusion.