# Let V be a vector space and $f,g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_m\in V^*$ its dual, prove that f is a linear combination of $g_i$'s iff $\cap ker g_i \subseteq kerf$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $f,g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_m\in V^*$  its dual, prove that $f$ is a linear combination of $g_i$'s iff $\cap \text{ker} g_i \subseteq \text{ker}f$

I already understand that if the intersection of $g_i$'s is empty, then it is a basis for the dual, and therefore $f$ is a linear combination of $g_i$'s. And I also managed to prove the foward direction (if $f$ is a linear combination of $g_i$, then $\cap \text{ker} g_i \subseteq \text{ker} f$, since that for any $v \in \cap ker g_i$ $f(v)=0=a_1g_1(v)=g_2(v)=\ldots=g_m(v)=0$). But I'm not finding a way to prove the reverse direction. Tried chatgpt but got only nonsense. Can someone give me a hint or post a duplicate (really didn't find it out here).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any kind of restriction over $dim(V)$?

Comment: The exercises doesnt poses any condition, but assume that V is finite dimensional.

Comment: Dint got it. It wanst supposed that g and f maps vectors on V to scalars on the field?

Comment: @Jorge The dual space is the space of linear maps $V \rightarrow F$ so $e_1$ and $e_1 + e_2$ are not valid outputs.

Comment: This already answered your (frequently asked) question: [Intersection of kernels and linear dependence of functionals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709781/intersection-of-kernels-and-linear-dependence-of-functionals) (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintersection%20of%20kernels%20of%20linear%20functionals&p=1)). Here is another duplicate: [How to prove this beautiful statement on linear forms using induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962931).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment it says we can assume $V$ is finite dimensional, so choose a basis $v_1, ... v_n$ of $V$, and $v_1^*, ... v_n^*$ is the dual basis. Now, both $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic to $F^n$, and the evaluation map $V^* \times V \rightarrow F$ is the dot product.

We now have a system of linear equations $f = \sum_{i=1}^m  a_i g_i$ with $n$ equations and $m$ variables. Gaussian elimination either gives a solution to this equation (which shows that $f$ is a linear combination of the $g_i$), or outputs some vector whose dot product with $f$ is nonzero, but whose dot product with $g_i$ are all zero. This is an element in $\cap ker(g_i)$ but not in $ker(f)$.

Comment: Got everything less the last part. I dont understand how if the system doesnt have a solution it outputs some vector (whose coordinates are $a_i$ )whose dot product with f is non zero but zero with all $g_i$. I will think more a bit.

Comment: Got it thanks!  Will comment the details later.

Comment: Gaussian elimination does row operations to try to find a solution. If there is no solution, then Gaussian elimination produces a list of row operations that when applied to the matrix, results in zero, but when applied to the solution vector, is not zero. However, row operations corresponds to left multiplication by a row vector, and left multiplying by a row vector means taking the dot product of that vector and the columns of the matrix.

Comment: Better look for duplicates (see above) than duplicate answers.  And actually, finite dimensionality is dispensable.