# Why is this functional norm-continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider the following fragment from the book "Lectures on von Neumann algebras":

[image]

Why is the marked line true? I'm probably missing some basic functional analytic fact here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a stronger topology, continuity is easier because it implies the convergence in the weaker topology.

If $x_j\to0$ in norm, then $\psi(x_j)\to0$ for all $\psi\in\mathscr F$, so $x_j\to0$ in $\sigma(\mathscr E,\mathscr F)$ and then $\varphi(x_j)\to0$.

Comment: Because the element of $\mathscr F$ are in the dual. They are continuous by definition.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that it is the continuous dual and not the algebraic dual. Now my question becomes trivial... Thanks again!

Comment: But nowhere it says that $\varphi \in \mathcal{E}^*$?

Comment: By assumption, $\varphi$ is just a linear map $\mathcal{E}\to \mathbb{C}$. There are no further assumptions, except that it is $\sigma(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{F})$ continuous on the unit ball.

Comment: $\varphi\in\mathscr E^*$ is the conclusion.