# If [x,z] = 0 $\implies$ [x,y] = 0, then y = $\alpha$z. True for infinite dimensional vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm reading Halmos's *Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces*, in which he makes several references to the infinite dimensional case. In my edition this item appears as question 6 at the end of section 14.

The proof for a finite dimensional space is fairly straightforward: 
y and z are linear functionals and span at most one dimensional subspaces of the dual space V', say Y and Z respectively. The annihilators Y$^0$ and Z$^0$ exist in the double dual V''. For a finite dimensional space V`` is "equal" (isomorphic) to V  and the condition [x,z] = 0 $\implies$ [x,y] = 0, equates to Y$^0$ is a subspace of Z$^0$, and they are both either of the same dimension as V, or one less.  This means that the vectors x (if any) for which [x,y] and [x,z] are non-zero exist in the same one dimensional subspace of V, so that if x$_0$ is a basis for this (1 dimensional) space and $\alpha $ = [x$_0$,y]/[x$_0$,z] then [x$_0$,z] $\alpha $ = [x$_0$,y], and if [w,y] is non-zero then w = $\beta$x$_0$ (because w is in the 1-D space with basis x$_0$) so that [w,y] = [$\beta$x$_0$,y] = $\beta$[x$_0$,y] = $\beta$[x$_0$,z] $\alpha $ = [$\beta$x$_0$,z] $\alpha $ = [w,z] $\alpha$

So, my question is, **is this true in an infinite dimensional space** ? I can't prove it or find a counter-example.

Comment: It's true. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709781/intersection-of-kernels-implies-linear-dependence-of-functionals).

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks for the reference: it will take me some time to work through it.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60460/ker-t-subset-ker-s-rightarrow-s-rt-when-s-and-t-are-linear-functionals) is a better link. You need to know the codimension of a non-zero linear functional on a vector space is $1$. For that, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330948/why-the-nontrivial-nullspace-of-a-linear-has-codimension-1).

Comment: @DavidMitra. A link in your original reference took me to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158173/linear-dependence-of-linear-functionals The accepted answer on this seems particularly simple (relying on every (infinite) vector space has a basis). Do you see any problem with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on this today, and my approach was much simpler.  Let $x_1$ and  $x_2$ be vectors such that $[x_1,z]$ and $[x_2,z]$ are nonzero. Let $\alpha_i = [x_i,y]/[x_i,z]$ for  $i=1, 2$  and $\beta = [x_2,z]/[x_1,z]$,  Consideration of $[x_2 - \beta x_1,z]$ shows $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$.  I may have messed up some details here - I am writing up my recollection of my solution.